# If condition is ignored and it always jumps to else statement

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android and this might be something pretty easy but i cant figure it out

```
public void login (View view){
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    String text= et.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("text = "+text);

    if(text.matches("User")){
        System.out.println("Im in if");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Order.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else if(text.matches("HOD")){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,HOD.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else if(text.matches("HR")) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,HR.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }else{

        System.out.println("Im in else");

    }

}
```

the if statement doesn't work and it always jumps to the else statement

Comment: Debug your code and check the value of `text`. And why are you using `matches`? why not `equals` or `contains`? you don't need regex for that.

Comment: use `equals` instead of `matches`

Comment: You may also want to `trim` your text

Comment: use `equal` or `equalsIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code because `matches` func is use for regex

```
 public void login (View view){
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
            String text= et.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("text = "+text);

            if(text.equals("User")){//if you want exact value otherwise you can use text.equalsIgnoreCase("your string")
                System.out.println("Im in if");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Order.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }else if(text.equals("HOD")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(this,HOD.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }else if(text.equals("HR")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(this,HR.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }else{

                System.out.println("Im in else");

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `matches()` expects a regex as a parameter. But you want to check if the Strings are the same. So you should use `if(text.equals(""))` instead of `matches("")`.